# How to remove this thermal cutout from a circuit?

Tags: thermal-cutoff

I'm trying to replace a thermal cutout in a convection heater. I'm kind of new in this world, and only have some rudimentary knowledge of soldering and circuits. I found this connection, and it's the one that's not working in the circuit. Now, I do have a replacement, so I'm seeking advice on how to replace it. If you have any other recommendations for a novice, also please let me know.

[image: topside]
[image: bottomside]

Comment: You need to know how to remove those rivets? Drill them out using a suitable size drill bit.

Comment: And then work out how to replace the rivets. Perhaps pop rivets or else nut, bolt and star washer.

Comment: Seems risky to replace a safety critical part without any experience in fixing this stuff.

Comment: How do you know that connection is bad?

Comment: It needs to be pointed out that soldering has no place here. The parts get too hot for that.  That's why you will find that all the connections are mechanical.